# How to remove a user from a custom audience through Marketing API

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I have a problem removing Users from Custom Audiences throught the Marketing API.

I add them without problem, the audience size is getting bigger, but when removing them from the audience later the size of the audience stays the same.
I add & remove them with the help of EXTERN_ID.

The Delete API call returns OK from facebook, and in the audience history i can see that there was a request to remove users,
but the audience size doesn't reduced no matter what i do (not even 24 hours later).

Has anyone succeed removing users from an audience through the Marketing API?
What am I doing wrong?

This is what i do:

**Adding the users (works as expected)**

```
{
  "is_raw": "true",
  "schema": [
    "EXTERN_ID",
    "APPUID"
  ],
  "data": [
    [
      "3182649",
      "1388384217887691"
    ],
    [
      "3182629",
      "1617862661561773"
    ]
 ],
  "app_ids": [
    "1234567890123"
  ]
}
```

**and this is the removal**

```
{
  "schema": "EXTERN_ID",
  "data": [
    "3182629",
    "3182649"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The removal step also needs the `is_raw` flag set to `true` as it defaults to `false`.